# Webpack 4 HMR not working with php slim

Tags: php, angularjs, webpack, slim, webpack-hmr

I need to reactivate my old project in AngularJS+PHP Slim. I've added Webpack 4 and it works perfectly with all my file changes in app running on port `9500`. But when I run also php slim (`php -S localhost:9500`) HMR stops working (webpack is compiling new bundle but page doesn't reload). App wont work properly without php slim running. Please tell me why is it happening and how to make it work.